# Questions about TEX when I try to Constuct a tablet

Tags: tables, errors, grouping

Excuse ME, when I try to construct a tablet in LaTeX, I got the following error message:

```
!Missing \endgroup inserted.
              <inserted text>
                            \endgroup
1.141  & \multicolumn{2}{c|c|}{Cash Flow at}
                                         \\ \cline{3-4}
```

Here is my original code in LaTeX. Could you please tell me How can I revise it to avoid the error?

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|r|r|}
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{c|c|}{Cash Flow at} \\ \cline{3-4}
\textbf{Action} & \textbf{Cash flow at $t=0$} & \textbf{$t=3$} & \textbf{$t=6$} \\ \hline
Lend \$3,000,000 in 3-years markets & -\$3,000,000 & +\$3,649,428.891  &0 \\  \hline
Roll over at $t=3$ for 3 years   & 0 &  -\$3,649,428.891 & +\$3,649,428.891+\tilde y\\ \hline
Borrow PV(\$3,649,428.891) in 6-years markets  & +\$3,100,554.785 &0 &-\$3,649,428.891 \\ \hline
\textbf{Total} & +\$100,554.7855 &0  & +\tilde y  \\  \hline
\end{tabular} \\
```

Answer (score 3):

In you example there are basically two problems:

1. The error is due to `\multicolumn{2}{c|c|}{Cash Flow at}` in which only one column specifier is required as second argument, which should be `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Cash Flow at}`.
2. Another problem is `\tilde y` which should be inside `$...$` symbols, i.e. `$\tilde{y}$`.

The corrected MWE will be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|r|r|}
\hline
&& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Cash Flow at} \\ \cline{3-4}
\textbf{Action} & \textbf{Cash flow at $t=0$} & \textbf{$t=3$} & \textbf{$t=6$} \\ \hline
Lend \$3,000,000 in 3-years markets & -\$3,000,000 & +\$3,649,428.891  &0 \\  \hline
Roll over at $t=3$ for 3 years   & 0 &  -\$3,649,428.891 & +\$3,649,428.891+$\tilde {y}$\\ \hline
Borrow PV(\$3,649,428.891) in 6-years markets  & +\$3,100,554.785 &0 &-\$3,649,428.891 \\ \hline
\textbf{Total} & +\$100,554.7855 &0  & +$\tilde {y}$  \\  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```